# Most efficient (de)serialization of lists of numbers

Tags: java, memory, serialization, bigdata, deserialization

I currently use [this serialization library](https://github.com/RuedigerMoeller/fast-serialization) to save my data as `Pair<double[], Double>` to a directory on my computer. The only data that is being serialized are numerical values in array form.

I've saved over 5 gigabytes of raw numerical data to that directory and I am expecting to continuously add more. I'm trying to future-proof the system to more efficiently store data (for use with very data hungry Neural Networks).

Is there a better way to store data rather than serializing `Pair<double[], Double>` objects? Should I save everything to .txt or CSV files instead? I need to do everything I can do to minimize the memory footprint on my hard drive and reduce deserialization times. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Store it in raw form. You can use the below given record format:

1. n: Short —> how many double values are there in this record
2. Followed by ‘n’ double values each occupying 8 bytes. First n-1 ate array elements from the pair and last one is value

You can use FileOutputStream for this purpose.

This will save you space by not storing unnecessary metadata about pair class.